# UK: Does my institution incur direct costs when I make use of an open access agreement?

Tags: united-kingdom, publishers, open-access

My institution has several publisher agreements that allow me to publish open access without cost (to me). What happens when I make use of such an agreement? Will my university incur direct costs (money that could be better spent elsewhere)? Will I take up a slot that could otherwise be used for other (more important) research?

Comment: This would depend entirely on the agreement your institution has signed with the publisher. Maybe you could ask your librarian?

Comment: I think there are some standard agreements that a large number of UK institutions have signed (e.g. https://beta.elsevier.com/open-access/agreements/jisc?trial=true). Would be interesting to learn about those.

Comment: If you're asking about specific agreements, it would probably be helpful to mention them and provide references/links for context for others (in the question body of your post).

Comment: Somebody has to pay. Journals aren't public charities or tax funded. Your university spends other monies to support your research. This isn't that different.

Comment: Yes of course: the nature of these deals is (presumably) that participating institutions pay a reduced fee. The question is whether these fees are commonly per-publication (in which case I wouldn't want to make use of them) or one-time (in which case I would want to use them).

Comment: Presumably, the number of papers published under the agreement will factor into any renegotiation of the agreement even if there is no per-publication fee.

Comment: @mritz_p Who are you to judge the importance of your research compared to anyone elses? Just publish your things and be happy about your publication! Don't think everone else is doing "better" research. In the EU, there is lots of funding that goes into open acces publishing and I am pretty sure there are also local government subsidies. I never heard of such a fund running out.

Comment: Where I work (not UK) there are some agreements where university pays in advance and then gets a certain maximum number of articles published open access. In such a situation it may be that your paper takes a slot away and others may not be able to use it (I could use our agreement early in the year but slots had run out in November.) If slots are not all used (which also happens), you just make good use of money already paid. Chances are not all agreements work like this though.

Comment: @Sursula The question was not what the questioner should do; and I think it is well of interest regardless of what consequences the questioner draws from the answers. And (see above) in my university slots can run out.

Comment: @mritz_p I have recently received an offer from a (smaller but reputable) publisher that they offer German unis and reserach institutions a flatrate deal where they pay a (reasonable!) fixed amount per year and have unlimited access to the publications and can submit as many papers for OA publication to their journals as they want at no APC. So if the deals with the Unis are similar elsewhere and with other publisher, there is no need to worry to take away ressources.